# Slow Updates for Single Records by Primary Key

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, innodb

I am using MySQL 5.5.

I have an InnoDB table definition as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col3` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col5` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `col6` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col7` datetime NOT NULL,
  `col8` datetime NOT NULL,
  `col9` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col10` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `col11` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_table1_on_ci_ai_tn_sti` (`col2`,`col4`,`col3`,`col9`),
  KEY `index_shipments_on_applicant_id` (`col4`),
  KEY `index_shipments_on_shipment_type_id` (`col9`),
  KEY `index_shipments_on_created_at` (`col7`),
  KEY `idx_tracking_number` (`col3`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7634960 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

The issue is UPDATES. There are about 2M rows in this table.

A typical UPDATE query would be :

```
UPDATE table1 SET col6 = 1 WHERE col1 = 7634912;
```

We have about 5-10k QPS on this production server. These queries are often in "Updating" state when looked at through the process list. The InnoDB locks show that there are many rec but not gap locks on `index_table1_on_ci_ai_tn_sti`. No transaction is waiting for lock.

My feeling is that the Unique Index is causing the lag but I'm not sure why. This is the only table we have that is defined this way using the Unique Index.

Comment: Thanks for the status report.  Was there a **question** you wanted to ask? (Assigning a new value to column `col6` shouldn't have any impact on the indexes shown. Assigning a new value to one of the columns in an index would require blocks in that index to be modified.)

Comment: Did you see any slow queries there?  The process list just shows some "snapshot".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `UNIQUE` key has any impact (in this case).

Are you really setting a `DATETIME` to "1"?  (Please check for other typos -- they *could* make a big difference.)

Are you trying to do 10K `UPDATEs` per second?

Is `innodb_buffer_pool_size` bigger than the table, but no bigger than 70% of available RAM?

What is the value of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit`?  1 is default and secure, but slower than 2.

Can you put a bunch of updates into a single transaction?  That would cut down the transaction overhead.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure where you are seeing DATETIME being defaulted to 1
2. It is 10k QPS not just updates. This type of update is about 5-10%.
3. Buffer pool is not an issue. Set to 48GB. Table is about 200 MB
4. innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit is set to 1. This is a production server and I do not want to set this any differently. However, if this was an issue, then I would have issues with my other tables.

Comment: @MYoussef IN your update query example you shown `SET col5 = 1` Here `col5` is datetime.

Comment: @MikeBrant Ah my fault. It is col6. I was looking at the table definition

Comment: 1K transactions per second with a setting of 1 -- that's 1000 disk hits per second.  That is more than standard disks can handle.  What is wrong with the numbers or my assumption about hardware?

Comment: The issue occurred this morning but updates were only around 60-100 updates per second.

Comment: OK, you are maxing out the I/O system.  I have given you a few things to pursue.